# Cardview Color is not keeping selected color

Tags: kotlin, android-cardview

I have been having an issue with my card view color. I have a where you can select the color of the cardView. The color sets to the color that is selected. However when you update the entry the color defaults to the default color as if you never selected a color to begin with. I have the code I believe is correct but i may be missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated.

`Adapter`

```
class NotesAdapter :
RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NotesViewHolder>() {
private var listener: OnItemClickListener? = null
private var arrList = ArrayList<Notes>()
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotesViewHolder {
    return NotesViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_rv_notes,parent,false)
    )
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return arrList.size
}

fun setData(arrNotesList: List<Notes>){
    arrList = arrNotesList as ArrayList<Notes>
}

fun setOnClickListener(listener1: OnItemClickListener){
    listener = listener1
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotesViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.itemView.tvTitle.text = arrList[position].title
    holder.itemView.tvDesc.text = arrList[position].noteText
    holder.itemView.tvDateTime.text = arrList[position].dateTime

    if (arrList[position].color != null){
       holder.itemView.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(arrList[position].color))
   }else{
       holder.itemView.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(R.color.ColorLightBlack.toString()))
    }


    if (arrList[position].imgPath != null){
        holder.itemView.imgNote.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(arrList[position].imgPath))
        holder.itemView.imgNote.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }else{
        holder.itemView.imgNote.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    if (arrList[position].webLink != ""){
        holder.itemView.tvWebLink.text = arrList[position].webLink
        holder.itemView.tvWebLink.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }else{
        holder.itemView.tvWebLink.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    holder.itemView.cardView.setOnClickListener {
        listener!!.onClicked(arrList[position].id!!)
    }

}

class NotesViewHolder(view:View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)


interface OnItemClickListener{
    fun onClicked(noteId:Int)
}

}
```

`BottomFragment`

```
 @Suppress("ASSIGNED_BUT_NEVER_ACCESSED_VARIABLE", "DEPRECATION", 
  "UNUSED_EXPRESSION")
  class NotesBottomSheetFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
private var selectedColor = "#E53935"


companion object {
    var noteId = -1
    fun newInstance(id:Int): NotesBottomSheetFragment {
        val args = Bundle()
        val fragment = NotesBottomSheetFragment()
        fragment.arguments = args
        noteId = id
        return fragment
    }
}
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi", "InflateParams")
override fun setupDialog(dialog: Dialog, style: Int) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style)

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes_bottom_sheet,null)
    dialog.run {
        setContentView(view)
    }

    val param = (view.parent as View).layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams

    val behavior = param.behavior

    if (behavior is BottomSheetBehavior<*>){
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object  : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback(){
            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            @SuppressLint("SwitchIntDef")
            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                ""
                when (newState) {
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING -> {
                    }
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING -> {
                    }
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> {
                    }
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED -> {
                    }

                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN -> {
                        dismiss()
                        behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
                    }

                }
            }

        })


    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes_bottom_sheet,container,false)

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    if (noteId != -1){
        layoutDeleteNote.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }else{
        layoutDeleteNote.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    setListener()
}

private fun setListener(){
    fNote1.setOnClickListener {

        imgNote1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tick)
        imgNote2.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote4.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote5.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote6.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote7.setImageResource(0)
        selectedColor = "#4e33ff"

        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","Blue")
        intent.putExtra("selectedColor",selectedColor)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)

    }

    fNote2.setOnClickListener {
        imgNote1.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tick)
        imgNote4.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote5.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote6.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote7.setImageResource(0)
        selectedColor = "#BAFFD105"

        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","Yellow")
        intent.putExtra("selectedColor",selectedColor)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)

    }

    fNote4.setOnClickListener {
        imgNote1.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote2.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tick)
        imgNote5.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote6.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote7.setImageResource(0)
        selectedColor = "#ae3b76"

        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","Purple")
        intent.putExtra("selectedColor",selectedColor)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)

    }

    fNote5.setOnClickListener {
        imgNote1.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote2.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote4.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote5.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tick)
        imgNote6.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote7.setImageResource(0)
        selectedColor = "#7CB342"

        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","Green")
        intent.putExtra("selectedColor",selectedColor)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)
    }

    fNote6.setOnClickListener {

        imgNote1.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote2.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote4.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote5.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote6.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tick)
        imgNote7.setImageResource(0)
        selectedColor = "#ff7746"
        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","Orange")
        intent.putExtra("selectedColor",selectedColor)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)
    }

    fNote7.setOnClickListener {
        imgNote1.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote2.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote4.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote5.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote6.setImageResource(0)
        imgNote7.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tick)
        selectedColor = "#000000"

        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","Black")
        intent.putExtra("selectedColor",selectedColor)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)
    }

    layoutImage.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","Image")
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)
        dismiss()
    }
    layoutWebUrl.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","WebUrl")
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)
        dismiss()
    }
    layoutDeleteNote.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent("bottom_sheet_action")
        intent.putExtra("action","DeleteNote")
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(requireContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)
        dismiss()
    }




}


}
```

`Create Note Fragment`

```
private fun updateNote(){
    launch {

        context?.let {
            val notes = NotesDatabase.getDatabase(it).noteDao().getSpecificNote(noteId)

            notes.title = etNoteTitle.text.toString()
            notes.subTitle = etNoteSubTitle.text.toString()
            notes.noteText = etNoteDesc.text.toString()
            notes.dateTime = currentDate
            notes.color = selectedColor
            notes.imgPath = selectedImagePath
            notes.webLink = webLink



            NotesDatabase.getDatabase(it).noteDao().updateNote(notes)
            etNoteTitle.setText("")
            etNoteSubTitle.setText("")
            etNoteDesc.setText("")
            layoutImage.visibility = View.GONE
            imgNote.visibility = View.GONE
            tvWebLink.visibility = View.GONE
            requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
        }
    }
}
private fun saveNote(){

    if (etNoteTitle.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(context,"Note Title is Required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    else if(etNoteSubTitle.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(context,"Note Sub-Title is Required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    else if (etNoteDesc.text.isNullOrEmpty()){

        Toast.makeText(context,"Note Description is Required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    else{

        launch {
            val notes = Notes()
            notes.title = etNoteTitle.text.toString()
            notes.subTitle = etNoteSubTitle.text.toString()
            notes.noteText = etNoteDesc.text.toString()
            notes.dateTime = currentDate
            notes.color = selectedColor
            notes.imgPath = selectedImagePath
            notes.webLink = webLink
            context?.let {
                NotesDatabase.getDatabase(it).noteDao().insertNotes(notes)
                etNoteTitle.setText("")
                etNoteSubTitle.setText("")
                etNoteDesc.setText("")
                layoutImage.visibility = View.GONE
                imgNote.visibility = View.GONE
                tvWebLink.visibility = View.GONE
                requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So my issue is with when updating the note the cardview does not retain the same color as when it was originally saved. SO change the card color works fine. It just the update portion that i am having an issue with. In my adapter it should trigger that the default color is different so it should retain the color not default.

I believe the issue is here

```
if (arrList[position].color != null){
        holder.itemView.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(arrList[position].color))
    }else{
        holder.itemView.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(R.color.ColorLightBlack.toString()))
    }
```

however I may be wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which part of your code you set your "arrList" and sent to adapter, maybe its always null, thats why it is not updating.

Comment: @Mert i added the full adapter in question code

Comment: I mean not the adapter code but where do you call your adapter's setData(arrNotesList: List<Notes>) function, what do you send with arrNotesList from your fragment to adapter. Because if you do not sent anything, adapter can not now your items and stays null all time.

Comment: @Mert I will have to check tomorrow. But the app works perfectly everything fires except when you up date a note and you don't reselect the color it defaults to my red. I am pushing an update to Google Play to fix search feature on Monday. I forgot to add the extra lowercase so it accepts Capital letters... However you can test the app... Nexus Notes ... Developer name is NerdSpace Software.. you will see what I mean about the color issue.. as long you keep selecting the color when update it's flawless.